# Material Design table not mapping to UserDataSource

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a hardcoded value in a UserDataSource that isnt being mapped to a Material Data table. Yet I can see the json when I print it to the screen... What am I missing?

**UPDATE: I discovered that the table populates normally when the checkbox column is removed... Any ideas what is wrong with that column?**

```
DATA: {{dataSource.data | json}}
<mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8 overflow-x-auto" [dataSource]="dataSource">

<div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="dataSource.loading$ | async">
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>

<!-- Checkbox Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
</ng-container>
<!-- end checkbox column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let e">tempName</mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="twodigitcoid">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Two digit coid</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let e">removeme</mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="awscoid">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>AWS coid</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let e">{{e.awsCoId}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="paiosLic">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PAIOS Lic In Use</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let e">{{e.paiosLicCount}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="paiosLicSupport">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PAIOS Support Lic In Use</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let e">{{e.paiosSupportCount}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)"></mat-row>
```

[image]

UserDataSource

```
export class UserDataSource implements DataSource<Company> {

private CompanyModelsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Company[]>([]);//emits values to the view
private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();
get data() { return this.CompanyModelsSubject.value; }

constructor(private svc: GreencardService) {}

//lets you subscribe to the data stream
connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Company[]> {
    console.log('datasource connected')
    return this.CompanyModelsSubject.asObservable();
}

disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    this.CompanyModelsSubject.complete();
    this.loadingSubject.complete();
}

//called in response to user actions- changes data steam that you connected to using connect()
loadData(lgid) {

    //hardcoded test
    this.loadingSubject.next(true); //also sets loading$ to true
    let com: Company[] = [new Company({ awsCoId: 1038 })];
    this.CompanyModelsSubject.next(com);
    this.loadingSubject.next(false);
    //end hardcoded test
}}
```

CompanyComponent

```
export class CompanyComponent{

    dataSource: UserDataSource;
    displayedColumns = ["select", "name",/*"twodigitcoid",*/ "awscoid","paiosLic","paiosLicSupport"];

    @Input() set lgid(value: number) {
        console.log('------\ncompanytable: ' + value);
        if (this.dataSource==undefined)
            this.dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.svc);
        this.dataSource.loadData(value);
    }
    @Output() coIdSelected= new SelectionModel<Company>(true, [],true);


    constructor(private svc: GreencardService) { }
    ....
    }
```

Comment: How does the component look like? Can you show it on stackblitz?

Comment: Im unfamilair with Stackblitz, but when I tried to set it up, it didnt recognize the DataSource input from @angular/cdk/table I did add th code above if that helps however

Comment: Can you post the code for the logic used in the `mat-checkbox` elements? Meaning code for `selection` and the functions `masterToggle`, `hasValue`, `isAllSelected`and so on? And are there any console errors?

Comment: @Rilcon42 i forked @jcuypers stackblitz example(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qd46pt) and replaced the ``<mat-header-cell>`` with basic ``<td>`` and it is working fine . can you please create a stackblitz example highlighting the problem ?

Comment: @Rilcon42 Didn't you get correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way we can help is if you either put this on stackblitz or similar so we can see it running, or you create a smaller example and test it there. Just by looking at it I can only guess that the problem is here:

```
DATA: {{dataSource.data | json}}
<mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8 overflow-x-auto" [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

should be

```
DATA: {{dataSource.data | json}}
<mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8 overflow-x-auto" [dataSource]="dataSource.data">
```

but there is no way for me to easily test this without stackblitz.

Comment: Im unfamilair with Stackblitz, but when I tried to set it up, it didnt recognize the DataSource input from @angular/cdk/table I did add the code above if that helps however

Comment: Do I get best answer then? Thanks!

Comment: @mraunova Sorry my comment above was unclear, I mean I tried what you suggested, but it did not change the output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `selection` object and `isAllSelected` function you are using them on checkbox but never defined them so defining them in your component should solve your problem something like

```
selection:any={
  hasValue:()=>{
    return true;//replace with your own logic
  },
  isSelected:()=>{
    return true;//replace with your own logic
  }

  };
  isAllSelected=()=>{
    return true;//replace with your own logic
  }
```

[Stackbliz working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foypbc)